# Translation function with multiple variables doesn't work

Tags: localisation

I have a problem using translate function.

This works:

```
$this->__("You can contact %s by calling %s.", $name, $phone);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$this->__("You can contact %1$s by calling %2$s.", $name, $phone);
```

And the problem is, that I would like to translate this as: "Please call %2$s to speak to %1$s." so the order is important.

Do you have any ideas why the second example doesn't work? I would appreciate any suggestions :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento uses PHPs [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) method. So instead of `%1$s` you'll have to use `%1\$s`

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I'm propose other method for display multiple variables with magento2.

I use this:

```
echo __('My name is [%1] and lastname(%2)',$name,$lastname);
```

Regards